# Spread operator on a Buffer object

Tags: node.js

Can someone please explain how does this code work:

```
[...Buffer('abc')]
```

the result is:

```
[ 97, 98, 99 ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, consider this piece of code:

```
console.log([...[1, 2, 3]]); //[1, 2, 3]
```

The Spread operator will try to take an array and transform it to a list of arguments.

Node.js's buffer object are actually arrays of bytes, a way to represent character and deal with binary data simultaneously. you can read more about it at https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html.

Now, since 'abc' is actually three ascii characters, each character will only take up one byte, and that byte will correspond to its ascii code.
You can get this by doing: `myString.charCodeAt(pos)`, in your case `'abc'.charCodeAt(0)` will return `97`.

So,

```
[...Buffer('abc')]
```

will actually return an array containing the ascii codes of each character of 'abc'. that is `[97, 98, 99]`

Since buffers' encoding is by default UTF-8, things will get more exciting when you are dealing with unicode.

```
console.log([...Buffer('漢字')]); //[230 188 162 229 173 151]
```

Sorry for potential typos and hope this helps.